# SQL to fill columns based on columns of associated table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have

- table `first_table` which has an FK to table `second_table`
- table `second_table` which has column called `name_field`

Now, I want to add a column in `first_table` called `name_field` and fill it with the one on the associated `second_table`.

How should I fill the values purely using SQL?

(this is Oracle, if that matters)

Comment: I would suggest using a view instead of changing the database schema (unless there's a good reason to).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I know what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a trigger in the FK table to do so automaticaly:

```
UPDATE table1
SET <field> = (select <field> from inserted where id=table1.id)
```

Comment: -1 because triggers are the work of the devil. They make system maintenance and debugging more difficult.

Comment: If you know that this field is only updated by a trigger, I can't find problems with that. Triggers are good for some task and not for anothers, is your selection of using it or not the work of the devil ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
update (select first_table.name_field nf1,
               second_table.name_field nf2
          from first_table,
               second_table
          where ... (join condition) ...
        )
set nf1 = nf2
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially there are 2 different tasks:
1) initialize values in the new column
I think that syntax below is the most universal 
`UPDATE table1
SET <field> = (select <field> from table2 where id=table1.id)`
2) synchronize values between 2 column in 2 tables based on the approach of j.a.estevan